# Backup and restore SQL Server database without FILESTREAM filegroup

Tags: sql-server, database, backup, restore

I use SQL Server and have a huge database with two filegroups:

- **Primary**: Which contains all the data except the large files (1MB+)
- **FILESTREAM (read/write)**: Which contains the large files

Now, the backup scenario is:

- Each Friday get a **full backup** (2 A.M).
- Each day on week except Friday get a **differential backup** (2 A.M)

Since the database is large, and it is in production on a remote server, whenever I want to bring the database to my local environment to create a test database (weekly), I have to bring both the primary and the filestream.

I would like to be able to change the way the backups and restores are done, in such a way that only had to bring the primary filegroup, ignoring the filestream. By this way, every week I would only bring the primary filegroup, and not all information that suppose the filestream.

I think there can be a lot of problems, and all filestream references can be lost when accessing the files. I would like to know if is it possible to modify the content of all filestream columns when performing a backup, or use a different filestream hosted in the test environment. Also, I've heard about Piecemeal Restore of only some Filegroups, but I have many doubts on how to carry it out.

**Question 1:** can I have this scenario?

**Question 2:** is it a good idea to have only one Full backup and bring differential backups/transaction logs to test environment?

**Question 3:** can I have better scenario to backup and restore?

I'm all ears to recommendations. If you have any example case, please show me with a T-SQL query.

Comment: Would better asked over at [dba.se] - voted to move.

Comment: @Filburt He just followed your recommendation and asked the same question in https://dba.stackexchange.com/, so it should be closed here (although the question is quite good IMO).

Comment: Can't be on both sites? I'm still learning the rules @AlbertoMartinez

Comment: As far as I know that would count also as a duplicate, an duplicated question are actively closed in StackExchange sites. But don't worry, if the question is closed it won't be bad for your reputation, also [there is a lot of discussion about StackOverflow vs DB Administrators](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/322009/49934).

Comment: It's not encouraged to cross-post - if you can agree your question would be received better on one of the sister sites and want to speed up the process of getting it moved, you can flag your own post for mod attention, asking to have it moved.